# How to use processStrategy with Object schema

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

How to use normalizr's `schema.Object` with `processStrategy`

It looks like Object doesn't have processStrategy option like Entity

```js
const deepNestedObj = new schema.Object({}, { 
  processStrategy: (value) => {
    someExternalService(value);
    return value;
  }
})
const schema = new schema.Entity(...)
```

I would like to do something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object does not use processStrategy. See options available in the [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#objectdefinition).

If your object has a unique ID, the recommendation is to use `schema.Entity` and its processing strategy.

Alternatively, since it looks like maybe `deepNestedObj` is something that's internal to your `schema.Entity`, you can just use the `processStrategy` option available on the Entity.